# 'Symbol' is undefined in IE after using babel

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have a `reactjs` app written using ES6 standards, and I use `webpack` to build it. The `webpack` loads the `js` modules using `babel-loader`. To be specific, I use the following versions of packages: 

`├── babel@5.8.34 
├── babel-core@5.8.34 
├── babel-loader@5.4.0 
└── webpack@1.12.6`

However, after building it, the IE 10 gives the following error `'Symbol' is undefined`. Shouldn't the `babel` be supposed to define the `Symbol`? Is there any specific configuration for `webpack` or `babel` I need to set in order to make it work? I use `{stage: 0}` configuration in my `.babelrc`.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you !

Comment: Could you add a stacktrace too?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Ok, I eventually found out that `babel` alone does no polyfill. Including script `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>` solved this issue for me.

Comment: is there a method that I can only inlucde this script in HTML like: <!--[if IE]>script(type='text/javascript').
            require('babel-core/browser-polyfill.js')
        <![endif]-->

Comment: I had the same issue in IE11 and this fixed it for me as well.   Thanks!

Comment: @Jurom, When I add this file in my html my IE crashes down :-(. Please help

Comment: @Rahul what version of IE? What do you mean by crash? Can you provide the error log?

Comment: IE Edge. It shows Internet Explorer not working. And I am unable to generate any log.

Comment: You can also achieve the same outcome via node modules `npm i -S @babel/core @babel/polyfill` and then `import "@babel/polyfill"` in your code.

Comment: Finally I found this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 95):

You can require polyfill in the entry point to your code so it will get bundled up with the rest of JavaScript.

One option is to use:

```
require('babel-polyfill');
```

Or:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
```

All of that is explained in [the documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/).

Comment: I was fighting this bug for hours!  THANK YOU

Comment: for some reason this doesn't work for me in IE10, IE11 so I am just including it as a separate script for IE as mentioned by Jurom. I probably would split it from my main bundle in webpack anyway.

Comment: Hello @Jurom and @ Lukasz, I am facing the same issue that Symbol and its functions like Symbol.Iterator is undefined in IE, by using this Babel Polyfill my page is not loading up but an error is coming up of IE crashing and asking to reload.

Comment: `babel-polyfill` fixed this issue for me. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me in Angular 10, but only if the `import "@babel/polyfill";
` statement was before `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';` (which makes sense because the Symbol error I was getting was from zone.js)

Answer (score 9):

This solution will work for sure, it worked for me when I encountered the error: 'Symbol' is undefined in IE . It worked earlier in Chrome and Firefox but IE was throwing this error.It took me few hours to find this solution.
I am using the latest React at this time react "react": "^16.5.0" on windows machine.

```
1. Install babel-polyfill
npm install --save-dev babel-polyfill
In package.json, it should have the following entries

"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  }

2. In index.js, add

    import babelPolyfill from 'babel-polyfill';
```

Problem should get solved

Comment: If you import the Babel polyfill in your index.js, you must install it as a regular dependency, not a dev dependency

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be the only way to get ie11 to work with the current way in which Babel and Webpack are working together to compile code. Why Babel is using es6 Symbols to build es5 modules in the first place is a mystery, as its clearly incompatible with older browsers, and compatibility with older browsers is the reason Babel exists.

Answer (score 7):

**OK,** I had the same issue, but in my case that was quite different, so basically you need to include script in the index file as below:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

But in my case, I already included that, after some investigations I found out that my proxy blocked the script...

So **make sure** you include it in index.html and also **make sure** that  you have access to the script from where you need it to avoid the error happening...best way just copy and paste the url in the browser...

But now which we get to this point, it's not talking about Symbol itself, what's Symbol which can not be recognised in IE?

> The Symbol() function returns a value of type symbol, has static
>   properties that expose several members of built-in objects, has static
>   methods that expose the global symbol registry, and resembles a
>   built-in object class but is incomplete as a constructor because it
>   does not support the syntax "new Symbol()".
>
> Every symbol value returned from Symbol() is unique.  A symbol value
>   may be used as an identifier for object properties; this is the data
>   type's only purpose.  Some further explanation about purpose and usage
>   can be found in the glossary entry for Symbol.
>
> The data type symbol is a primitive data type.

Comment: This fixed it for me also. I used the Babel online compiler and included this script in my HTML, voila.

Comment: i can't believe this one line works! chasing polyfills for react + material ui for days and this fixed all of it with a single line.

Answer (score 4):

in documentation about Runtime

```
// in bash
npm install babel-transform-runtime --save-dev

// in gulpfile
.pipe(babel({
  plugins: ['transform-runtime']
}))
```

edit:
better yet on heroku in prod mode use --save instead of --save-dev

Comment: This module is now called `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error in an Angular app, you need to un-comment the following lines in polyfills.ts -

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```