# Execute injected javascript in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, reactjs

I'm injecting a bit of code into my website (in other words the return value of http://localhost/FibReactHello/#):

```
<div id="reactAppEntryPoint">
  <script src="http://localhost/FibReactHello/scripts/bundle.js"></script>
</div>
```

This JS is run and converted to my react application as I would expected in both Chrome and IE11.  In Firefox the JS is not executed.  It just sits there like a bump on a log.  The JS should have caused some HTML to be generated giving me arbitrary site content.

Here's the jQuery:

```
<div id="appEntrypt">
            <button onclick="alertMe(event);">Inject React into Boost</button>
        </div>

        <script>
            function alertMe(e) {//crappy named function
                //e.preventDefault();
                console.log('js works');
                var url = "http://localhost/FibReactHello/#";
                resetState();
                $.ajax({
                    url: url, success: function (result) {
                        $("#appEntrypt").html(result);
                        write(result);
                    },
                    async: true
                });
                /*
                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    $("#appEntrypt").html(data);
                    write(data);
                });*/
                return null;
            }

            function write(data) {
                console.log(data);
            };

            function resetState() {
                document.getElementById('appEntrypt').innerHTML = "";
            };
        </script>
```

Comment: what is the response from `"http://localhost/FibReactHello/#";` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my Ajax call to dataType 'script' as opposed to 'html'.  Also pointed directly to my bundle.js file.  The script executes in Chrome and Firefox.

```
        $.ajax({
                url: devUrl,
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log("successfully got script")
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    var output = "Error: " + errorThrown + ' status: ' + status + ' statusText: ' + xhr.statusText
                    console.log("failed to get script: " + output);
                },
                contentType: 'application/javascript',//IE
                dataType: 'script',
                cache: false,//required for IE
                crossDomain: true,//required for IE
            });
```

In IE this solved the issue of grabbing the script.  But in my case my bundle.js needed a polyfill to learn IE how to run jabbascrept:

['Symbol' is undefined in IE after using babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828840/symbol-is-undefined-in-ie-after-using-babel)

Comment: I think it's more to do with your `url` than `dataType`. Also, `async:true` in jQuery's ajax is redundant. It's async by default. Also, just to make sure that  you're getting the right `dataType` you can do `curl -IL http://localhost/FibReactHello/scripts/bundle.js | grep 'Content-Type'` and check the "Content-type" there.

Comment: @shriek Why do you think there is an issue with the url?  I removed the async part per your comment.

Comment: Oh, sorry about not following up on this. I completely forgot about this. Reason being that your previous url was `http://localhost/FibReactHello/#` instead of `http://localhost/FibReactHello/scripts/bundle.js` which was fixed on your second try. Sometimes when you're not directly hitting the static files (js/css) it's upto the api creators to implement what `Content-type` that's to be delivered. One way to make sure is to curl the endpoint and check the Content-type yourself and see if you're getting the right file.