# Vue.js not loading on IE11 with error 'Symbol' is undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

Using [Vue.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue) on my webapp work on most browsers, except IE11. I tried the default [babel-preset-es2015](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015), also tried the [babel-preset-es2015-ie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015-ie), but no luck: the code still not running on IE11 with ***'Symbol' is undefined*** error.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]  << also tried es2015-ie
}
```

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --port 3000 --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "vue": "^2.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.20.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^1.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "vue-loader": "^9.8.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Symbol' is undefined in IE after using babel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828840/symbol-is-undefined-in-ie-after-using-babel)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed by [@Leonid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2594597/leonid-vasilyev), I was missing browser-polyfill script, as described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33831169/4838205). Working fine now on IE11 (and other browsers).

Here is what I did:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-polyfill
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/main.js'],
  ....
  ....
}
```

Comment: Because this is a polyfill (which will run before your source code), we need it to be a dependency, not a devDependency.
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill#installation
(So instead of --save-dev, use --save as a small fix)

Answer (score 0):

I'll rather prefe updating `webpack.mix.js` instead. Then using the updated version of `@babel/polyfill` and `babel-loader`. And these @babel/core babel-preset not necessary. corejs 3 is more recent version but cant seem to work it out. Please anyone knows how to make import core-js/stable work, lemme know!

With NPM:

```
npm install babel-loader @babel/polyfill --save
```

webpack.mix.js

```
module: {
      rules: [{
          test: /\.js?$/,
          exclude: /(bower_components)/,
          use: [{
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: mix.config.babel()
          }]
      }]
  }
```

And finally import @babel/polyfill at the beginning of your main/js or app.js file

```
import '@babel/polyfill';
```

Dependencies:

```
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.4",
"babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
"vue": "^2.6.11",
```