# Symbol is undefined in IE 9-11 because of babel for-of transform plugin

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, for-of-loop

I have couple of `for ... of` loops in my code and after babel transforms it I get `Symbol is undefined` in IE browsers.
I tried to dig it and found that `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of` transforms for-of to

```
for (var _iterator2 = notifications[Symbol.iterator](), _step2; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion2 = (_step2 = _iterator2.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion2 = true) {
```

which fails. I also tried `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol` which seems like what I need but I'm not sure, I'm still newbie in this area. So far no luck.

I'm also aware of `babel-polyfill` (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33828840/3606603) question) but it's quite big and I think I'll include it as last resort.

Comment: If you want to use symbols in legacy IE, you will have to include the polyfill or write one yourself. No other way around it.

Comment: So `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol` isn't what I'm looking for?

Comment: No, it is, you'll just need to find [a polyfill for `Symbol`](https://github.com/medikoo/es6-symbol) as well if you want to use `for ... of` loops.

Comment: Yeah, got it. This polyfill in your link didn't worked for me, it broke something else :) But I've got the idea, thanks a lot. If you'll convert your comments to answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @valentjedi If your target is IE9 you are going to be looking for *a lot* of individual polyfills. Either way, Babel's polyfill is based on [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#commonjs) and a custom [regenerator runtime](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-regenerator/). You'd be better of including the required polyfills from core-js as a single-source.

Comment: I've got it already, but for now babel-polyfill is too big for me. I'll add it later, when its size won't affect as much on my bundle as now.