# The code of `for-of` circlation transport by babel not support some browser

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, babeljs, for-of-loop

I had some es6 codes in my react project like this:

````
``` javascript
for (const v of [0, 1, 2,]) { /* doSth*/ }
```
````

and it works well after transport to es5 every where.
however, if I change them like those:

````
``` javascript
const arr = [0, 1, 2,];
for (const v of arr) { /* doSth*/ }
```
````

then it throw an error that `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Symbol` in iPhone 5c.
I tried both `foreach` `for-in` and the pure `for` circulation, they all works well in that old device.
But, I need do something like `async () => { for (...) { await doSthAysnc; } }`, and it cannot use `foreach`.
What's more, `for-of` was very dangerous, and pure `for` is very ugly. so if possibly, I prefer to use `for-of`.
thanks.

@Bergi Well, that's the codes it transpiles to:
    `javascript
    ("================================================================"),m=["a","b","c"],e.prev=38,v=c.a.mark(function e(n){return c.a.wrap(function(e){for(;;)switch(e.prev=e.next){case 0:return e.next=2,new Promise(function(e){return setTimeout(function(){return e(n)},1e3)});case 2:case"end":return e.stop()}},e,t)}),y=!0,b=!1,w=void 0,e.prev=43,_=m[Symbol.iterator]();case 45:if(y=(x=_.next()).done){e.next=51;break}return E=x.value,e.delegateYield(v(E),"t2",48);case 48:y=!0,e.next=45;break;case 51:e.next=57;break;case 53:e.prev=53,e.t3=e.catch(43),b=!0,w=e.t3;case 57:e.prev=57,e.prev=58,!y&&_.return&&_.return();case 60:if(e.prev=60,!b){e.next=63;break}throw w;case 63:return e.finish(60);case 64:return e.finish(57);case 65:e.next=69;break;case 67:e.prev=67,e.t4=e.catch(38);case 69:console.log("================================================================"),`

Comment: Please show us what it *transpiles* to.

Comment: I want to, but it's really hard to found them through the built code.

Comment: Ah, regenerator :-) You could have dropped the minification step to make the debugging easier, but I think I found the issue nonetheless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an array literal directly inside `for … of` enables an [extra transpiler optimisation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-for-of/#options-optimization) that causes it not to use iterables. In the default cause, it will try to find the `m[Symbol.iterable]` method which fails in legacy environments.

In can see three solutions:

- [Import the `babel-polyfill`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35320045/1048572) to enable symbols and iterators
- Use [loose mode](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-for-of/#optionsloose) which hopefully always uses the array path
- Use the [`transform-for-of-as-array` babel plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-for-of-as-array) instead which always transpiles to array loops